# Time stamp of File in PHP - filemtime()

Tags: php, image, filemtime

I am trying to get the time stamp using filemtime() of each file and display it on the web page in PHP, I tried much as possible but only getting 1 Jan 1970 as time stamp in return.

Which basically means the timestamp function is not getting the file.

Could you please fix anything wrong in the code.
Thanks

Rahil

```
foreach($images as $image) 
{
    $count+=1;
    if($count==1)
    {
        echo '<div class="box boxgallery">';
    }
        /* ATTEMPT ONE*/
        :clearstatcache();
        $path="A2storage/'.$image.'";
        $date = date(filemtime($path));

        echo "Captured at: " . date('h:i A', $date);

        /* ATTEMPT  TWO:*/ 
        echo date ("H:i:s   | ", filemtime($image));
        print basename($image) ."<br />";

        echo '<a class="vlightbox1" href="A2storage/'.$image.'"/> <img src="A2storage/'.$image.'"/></a>';


    if($count>=$count_each_column)
    {
        $count=0;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump(file_exists($path))`

Comment: $tim=var_dump(filemtime($image));
echo $tim;

Gives O/P: bool(false)

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unwanted single quotes in value of `$path`

```
 $path="A2storage/'.$image.'";
```

Change to

```
 $path="A2storage/$image";
```

Also 1st parameter of `date` function should be format which is missing.

```
$date = date(filemtime($path));
```

Change to

```
$date = filemtime($path);
```

Then this should print the time

```
echo "Captured at: " . date('h:i A', $date);
```

Comment: Works, Thank you!